# How to update the NgModel of a transcluded element

Tags: angularjs

I need to change the model of a transcluded selectbox from inside the directive. Usually I'd do it with `require: '?ngModel'` but this only works if the directive in attached on the element as an attribute which transclusion cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

Transcluded content is bound to the parent scope of the directive.

One can use the `ng-form` directive to enclose the transcluded ngModelControllers and put those controller on the isolate scope of the directive.

```
  <ng-form name="$ctrl.form1">
    <fieldset>
      Transcluded content<br>
      <ng-transclude></transclude>
    </fieldset>
  </ng-form>
```

Then one can use the [$setViewValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue) method of the ngModelController:

```
  controller: function() {
    this.radioChange = function(val) {
      console.log(val);
      this.form1.sel1.$setViewValue(val);
      this.form1.sel1.$render();
    }
  },
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/dL1iYCntKKF86hzvhZno?p=preview)